# How to use trace marker in ftrace?

Tags: kernel, trace, ftrace

How to use trace marker in `ftrace` in order to record user events? I use the following, but the compiler cannot define `WR_ONLY`:

```
static int trace_fd = -1;

    void trace_write(const char *fmt, ...)
    {
            va_list ap;
            char buf[256];
            int n;

            if (trace_fd < 0)
                    return;

            va_start(ap, fmt);
            n = vsnprintf(buf, 256, fmt, ap);
            va_end(ap);

            write(trace_fd, buf, n);
    }


    [...]

    trace_fd = open("trace_marker", WR_ONLY);
```

And later, using the `trace_write()` function to record into the `ftrace`
buffer.

```
    trace_write("record this event\n")
```

The compiler error:

```
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
trace_fd = open("trace_marker", WR_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an error in the [ftrace documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/ftrace.html) where you seem to have copied your code from. Try `O_WRONLY` (`#include <sys/fcntl.h>` to get its definition) instead of `WR_ONLY`.

Note that you'll also need the full path to `trace_marker`, which is `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker` or `/sys/kernel/tracing/trace_marker` depending on your kernel version and mount location of the `tracefs`.